# how to get Id inside table tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have html and script like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th id="vehicleNo">Vehicle No.</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="vehicleNo"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p>When you leave the input field, a function is triggered which transforms the input text to upper case.</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("vehicleNo").onchange = function() {myFunction3()};

var time1;
var time2;
var text1 = "greater than 30 sec";
var text2 = "less than 30 sec";
function myFunction3() {
var d2 = new Date();
var y = document.getElementById("vehicleNo");
y= d2.getTime();
time2 = y;
var checkTime2 = d2.toLocaleTimeString();
console.log(this.time2);
console.log(this.checkTime2);
//console.log(time2);
}
</script>

</body>
```

why the value not showing on console? am I wrong in accessing the id in the table tag? how to access id inside table tag? many thanks

Comment: Because you attached the change handler to the table cell with the ID `vehicleNo`, and not the actual input field …?

Answer (score 0):

To run the code you need the change the following things:

1. Bind the change handler with input field rather than the table cell
2. Bind the change handler on load of page so that whenever user make change in control value the event can trigger

For your reference :

```
  <html>
<head>
<script>
function myfunction(){
document.getElementById("vehicleNo").onchange = function() {myFunction3()};
}


var time1;
var time2;
var text1 = "greater than 30 sec";
var text2 = "less than 30 sec";
function myFunction3() {
var d2 = new Date();
var y = document.getElementById("vehicleNo");
y= d2.getTime();
time2 = y;
var checkTime2 = d2.toLocaleTimeString();
console.log(this.time2);
console.log(checkTime2);
//console.log(time2);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload ="myfunction()">

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Vehicle No.</th>
        <td><input type="text" id="vehicleNo" name="vehicleNo"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p>When you leave the input field, a function is triggered which transforms the input text to upper case.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh thank you, i thought we can acces id inside table tag